# Android TV: Focus moved to View in ScrollView that is outside visible part of ScrollView

Tags: android, android-tv

I have a vertical row of focusable Views inside a ViewGroup in a ScrollView.
Above it are some focusable buttons. 
When the ScrollView has views scrolled up outside it's top, and I move focus horizontally between the buttons, the views in the scroll view ABOVE the visible part of the the scrollview get focus, since they are in the same horizontal area as the buttons I guess.

This seems like very incorrect behaviour. 
Is anybody else seeing this behaviour or know of a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not add your code, I can only suggest adding the following attributes to your buttons:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/button2"
    ... />
<Button
    android:id="@id/button2"
    android:nextFocusLeft="@id/button1"
    ... />
```

You can get more information here:

https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation#Direction

Comment: Thanks. I didn't show code since I'm making a cross-platform library and it's kind of all spread out with no xml. 

Hard-coding the button's nextFocus will be a great workaround. 
But I'm still thinking the hidden views in the scrollview shouldn't be focused at all.

Comment: You can use setNextFocusRightId and setNextFocusLeftId methods in your code.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setNextFocusRightId(int)

Comment: Maybe the scrollview itself gets the focus, not the items in it... Use the following methods to prevent it from getting focused:

        scrollView.setFocusable(false);
        scrollView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

Comment: Thanks.

The scrollview did get focus, turned that off with

`focusable = android.view.View.NOT_FOCUSABLE` (kotlin)

But still getting focus on hidden, scrolled up views.

I guess I'll have to use setNextFocusRightId etc, which will be a hack and pain, since I don't have id's on any views/buttons etc.

Comment: Why don't you use RecyclerView instead of ScrollView? You probably wouldn't experience those focusing issues.

Comment: I was using ListView and it was the same, so ScrollView was actually a simplification to maybe avoid the problem. 

Would like to use RecyclerView, but it doesn't quite work with the overlaying cross-platform library.